# Cookies blocked because host

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, ionic-framework, cookies

I'm having a problem in a ionic proyect, where a proxy is used to connect to the API when debugging in the browser. This application connects to an API that has a PHPSESSID cookie for the host myaplication.domain, but Chrome thinks the host is localhost because of the proxy, rejecting the cookie with the message: ***This set-cookie was blocked because its domain cookie was invalid with regards to the current host url***

Is there a setting in chrome, or some way in ionic to allow cookies from other host? It is just for development and I don't have control over the API so solutions require to be client-side.

Comment: Not sure there’s any kind of setting for this, I think this is far from any reasonable use case. This would really rather be the responsibility of the proxy here, I think, to manipulate any responses accordingly, so that the Set-Cookie header matches the host name the proxy uses to pass the whole thing along to the client.

Comment: I agree with you, I will try to find out if that's possible to configure. I think working with ionic with a proxy like this is very common (im new to ionic), and someone would've done it before, but not finding an answer made me think that I might have been missing something obvious.